# Bank of America issue

Tags: yodlee

Dear Yodlee / @apoorv / @Shreyans,

A client tried adding a Bank of America account. Bank of America is site ID 409, but when adding an account via the Site-based APIs, we get back this response:

`{
  "errorOccurred": "true",
  "exceptionType": "com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException",
  "referenceCode": "_55558c4f-9107-4ae2-b2ef-1118b5701fca",
  "message": "Invalid argument value: Site is not having any content service that is enabled and is not custom409 for: siteId"
}`

I used the SiteTraversal/getAllSites API to check the list and it appears that Site 409 has been removed and there is now Site 2852 "Bank of America (US)" instead.

I have a few questions.

a) can you confirm that 409 has been removed?

b) if you just remove banks from your system and give them different ID numbers what happens to all the accounts added to that bank? what would have happened to my users with accounts under Site 409 "Bank of America (US)"? They would just stop working?

c) like all Yodlee-based apps, we need to cache the bank list within our own database to give the users a good experience. If we have to use the APIs constantly to get basic bank data, our apps would be unusably slow. So we cache them, obviously.

However, if you are deleting banks from your list regularly, how are we supposed to handle this on our side?

The SiteTraversal/getAllSites API data response is MASSIVE - really massive. This usually isn't an issue. We just run through it and create/update our internal cached bank records.

But if we have to catch deletions, that changes everything. We would have to hold the entire response JSON data in memory, even though it is enormous, extract all the site ID numbers, then grab all of our cached site ID numbers, and run them against each other to see which ID numbers are not in both lists, which means those are now removed,. The server memory required for such a large operation is substantial, and I don't want to have to do that if there is another way.

What is your guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

`a) can you confirm that 409 has been removed?`

Yes it has been disabled.

```
b) if you just remove banks from your system and give them different ID numbers what happens to all the accounts added to that bank? what would have happened to my users with accounts under Site 409 "Bank of America (US)"? They would just stop working?
```

If we remove and create new site for the same FI, then ideally we migrate the users from old site to the new site.

Or

We leave the users on the old site with cache refresh turned on and hence those accounts refreshes on a daily basis but no new accounts can be added to the disabled site.

```
c) like all Yodlee-based apps, we need to cache the bank list within our own database to give the users a good experience. If we have to use the APIs constantly to get basic bank data, our apps would be unusably slow. So we cache them, obviously.

However, if you are deleting banks from your list regularly, how are we supposed to handle this on our side?
```

We usually recommend calling the SiteTraversal/getAllSites once in a day and update the cached data at your end.

Thanks for you feedback at the end, we will definetely take this into consideration and see what we can do to help on this.